# How to trigger correctly a random.choice() after button selection in Flask?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web, flask

i am a beginner python student and I trying to build a website that has a single button where each time you click on it a new window will pop up with a random flash game.

now, my button is working but it always opens the same flash game and only when i refresh the page and click again it loads a new game.

can someone please explain to me what is going wrong and how can i fix this? :)

before that i scraped a article with around 150 links to flash games that are now in a .txt file like this for example:

http://www.tapeonline.com/snowball/

http://www.gamesforwork.com/games/play-4626-Necrathalon-Flash_Game

http://www.adobe.com/macromedia/holiday2004/

http://www.kongregate.com/games/arawkins/dolphin-olympics-2

here is my code: 
flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import random

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/" , methods=['POST','GET'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return redirect("/")
    else: 
        a = open('gamelinks.txt','r')
        b = a.read().split()
        a.close()
        return render_template('index.html', game=random.choice(b))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{%block head %}

{% endblock %}
<title>FLASHER</title>
{% block body %}


<form action = '{{ game }}' method='POST' target="_blank">
    <input type='submit', name='submit', id='submit', value='Play Game'>
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it chooses randomly only once. 
When you load a page random value is assigned to game variable and it stays that way until you refresh page. 
You might want to use JS for refreshing page after submitting form: 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp